# div position absolute in table cell

Tags: html, html-table, css-position

I have a  element which has `<div>` element in each `<td>` element. I need to make a div with position absolute. But it does't seem work.

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/eric777/bZDQT/).

Comment: what is your problem? maybe: http://jsfiddle.net/eric777/bZDQT/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set some width and height of the table to get that work.
As the only element inside table is div which is absolute, so it didn't get calculated.

Answer (score 0):

To position absolute inside an element I think you need to use margin instead of the usual top, left, etc.

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 0 0 0; 
}​
```

edit:
take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/bZDQT/6/